# Ubuntu 16.04 on Hyper-V: Gave up waiting for root device

Tags: boot, 16.04, virtualization, hyper-v

I'm testing out importing an Ubuntu 16.04 VM into Hyper-V for my company. We normally use VirtualBox, but we've also imported the image into VMWare with very few issues.

Hyper-V seems to be a lot more finicky. I used a program called "StarWind V2V converter" to create a VHD file with the VMDK file we use in VBox. The boot process hangs at a few points and then continues. But then it runs into a series of errors:

[image]

after displaying several of these over 10 seconds or so, the boot drops into (initramfs).

Running `cat /etc/fstab` from initramfs produces no output.

Does anyone have suggestions for approaching this issue? I'm not very familiar with Ubuntu or Hyper-V, so I'm at a bit of a loss here. I've been researching these errors but it seems like they can be caused by a variety of problems. I haven't found anything so far that has helped.

I'm currently converting the VMDK to a VHDX (instead of VHD). But that's mostly for a lack of better ideas.

Any help or just pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be because I did not have Hardware Enablement (HWE) installed. I tried installing a fresh version of Ubuntu 16.04 on Hyper-V and ran into similar issues where the installer was unable to find a disk drive.

Installing a fresh OS with HWE solved the issue. I went back and installed HWE on my initial VBox VM (`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04`). After converting the VMDK to VHDX and trying again, my issues were resolved.